# How we can execute html & jscript code in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to set ranges for morning/evening/afternoon/night using hours with these ranges:

```
Good Evening: 16:00 to 23:00
Good Morning: 4:00 to 11:59
Afternoon: 12:00 
Good Afternoon: 12:00 to 16:00
```

**HTML Code:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Greeting Message using JavaScript</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <label id="Greetings"></label>
</body>

<script>
      document.write("<h2>");
      var day = new Date();
      var hr = day.getHours();
      if (hr >= 4 && hr < 12) {
          document.write("Good Morning");
      } else if (hr == 12) {
          document.write("Afternoon");
      } else if (hr >= 12 && hr <= 16) {
          document.write("Good Afternoon");
      } else if (hr >= 16 && hr <= 23) {
          document.write("Good Evening");
      } else {
          document.write("Good Night");
      }
      document.write("</h2>");
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this properly in powershell rather thank trying to hammer javascript into the mix? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330512/in-powershell-profile-test-for-morning-afternoon-or-evening-and-make-the-sel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use internet explorer COM objects to process HTML code:

```
# start internet explorer COM
$ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'

# load your html
$ie.Navigate('file://C:\test\test.html')

# Get the output of a particular node, based on your example:
$ie.Document.body.childNodes | 
  Where NodeName -eq 'H2' | 
  Select -ExpandProperty InnerText

Good Evening

# dispose of the IE object
$ie.Quit()
```

Note that you will probably have to alter your ActiveX security settings to execute `<script>`. So if your jscript doesn't run, try making IE visible: `$ie.Visible = $true`, refresh, and check for an ActiveX warning.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-tell-if-activex-is-enabled-in-internet-explorer/